# Por que no puedo acceder a los datos del TD con JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Estoy estancando en un problema ya que no puedo acceder a los ultimos datos de un td con mi codigo de js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

seguí los pasos que me explico un colega del portal pero no entiendo por que no puedo acceder a estos con mi codigo js

```
<script>
$("#btnEnviar").click(function () {
    var numero = $("#txtNumero").val(); 
    var cliente = $("#txtClienteSAP").val();
    var fecha = $("#txtFecha").val();
    var formaPago = $("#txtFormaPago").val();
    var NombrePago = $("#txtNombrePago").val();
    var codigoPago = $("#txtCodigoPago").val();
    var notaPedido = $("#txtNotaPedido").val();
    var direccion = $("#txtDireccion").val();
    var fechaEntrega = $("#txtFechaEntrega").val();
    var clienteNombre = $("#txtNombre").val();
    var rut = $("#txtRut").val();
    var codigoSAP = $("#txtCodigoSAP").val();
    var codigo = $("#txtCodigo").val();
    var codigoItem = $("#txtCodigoItem").val();

    var params = {
        Numero: numero,
        ClienteSAP: cliente,
        Fecha: fecha,
        FormaPago: formaPago,
        Nombre_Pago: NombrePago,
        CodigoSAP_Pago: codigoPago,
        NotasPedido: notaPedido,
        Direccion: direccion,
        FechaEntrega: fechaEntrega,
        Nombre_Cliente: clienteNombre,
        Identificador: rut,
        CodigoSAP_Cliente: codigoSAP,
        CodigoSAP: codigo,
        Codigo: codigoItem
    }

    let Datos = [];
    document.querySelectorAll("#tableResultContent tr").forEach((fila) => {
        let dato = {};
        dato.NombrePedProducto = fila.querySelector(".tdNombre").innerHTML;
        dato.Nombre = fila.querySelector(".tdNombre").innerHTML;
        dato.UnidadMedida = fila.querySelector(".tdUnidad").innerHTML;
        dato.Precio = Number(fila.querySelector(".tdPrecio").innerHTML);
        dato.Stock = Number(fila.querySelector(".tdStock").innerHTML);
        dato.Cantidad = Number(fila.querySelector(".tdCantidad").innerHTML);
        dato.Descuento = Number(fila.querySelector(".tdDescuento").innerHTML);
        dato.Observacion = fila.querySelector(".tdObservacion").innerHTML;
        dato.Total = Number(fila.querySelector(".tdTotal").innerHTML);
        dato.Codigo = Number(fila.querySelector(".tdCodigo").innerHTML);//Datos que no puedo obtener
        dato.CodigoSAP = Number(fila.querySelector(".tdCodigoSAP").innerHTML);//Datos que no puedo obtener
        Datos.push(dato);
    });

    var pedidoDato = {
        listaPedido: Datos,
        pedido: params
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Crear',
        data: pedidoDato,
        success: function (data) {
            
        }
    });
})
```

Como ven en el script sigo los  mismos pasos que tiene el codigo, si pongo el id de otro td en el codigo me lo toma y puedo realizar las consultas en mi controlador

```
[HttpPost]
 public JsonResult ListarPedido(PedidoViewModel pedido,List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedido)
    {
        //aquí alguna lógica, por ejemplo recorrerlo

        foreach (var item in listaPedido)
        {
            pedido.Cantidad = item.Cantidad;
            pedido.Nombre = item.Nombre;
            pedido.UnidadMedida = item.UnidadMedida;
            pedido.Descuento = item.Descuento;
            pedido.NombrePedProducto = item.NombrePedProducto;
            pedido.CodigoSAP = item.CodigoSAP;
            pedido.Codigo = item.Codigo;
            pedido.Stock = item.Stock;
            pedido.Observacion = item.Observacion;
            pedido.Total = item.Total;
        };
        return Json(new { listaPedido }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Solo necesito obtener estos datos para poder terminar el proceso de ingreso en mi sistema agradeceria mucho si me pueden ayudar con este problema

Comment: Porque lo estás convirtiendo a Number y no es número. Fíjate que en nombre y observación no se convierte a Number

Comment: Tienes razon bro no me habia fijado en ese detalle muchas gracias